# Mock payments for student projects

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I need to create as my first year project a php application that requires to handle payments. The business model I would like to implement requires that I have to both receive and make payments to the customers (basically I need to handle transactions between 2 customers, and I get a small fee of the transaction value).

I have never used any payment API, but that's not the point. The problem is that I would like something that has a sandbox mode where I can experiment and does not require business/premium accounts or to make bank requests. I was thinking about PayPal, but it seems it requires a business account.

Is there such an API?

Comment: Most payment APIs like PayPal and the various ACH providers offer some form of developer mode. Are you sure your assignment is to simply create an interface to an existing payment service, not to create something from scratch? And are you up to either when you can't even google for payment APIs without asking for help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [PayPal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).  You can get up and running in the sandbox very easily.

Specifically, you'll want to look at the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Stripe](https://stripe.com), which has a great API and a testing mode: https://stripe.com/docs/testing

It's free and there is no "premium account".

Comment: Very easy for student project

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems it requires a business account.

Business account is only for production API. For development you use sandbox and there's no such requirement.